# Laravel Environment detection

Tags: php, linux, laravel, terminal

I want custom environment detection. I know how the existing Laravel environment detection works, but I want a more dynamic way. I want to **EXPORT** a variable in my Ubuntu env, suggesting it's *'development'* or *'production'*, as opposed to using host names and IP addresses.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do in my projects is I create a file "app/bootstrap/environment.php"

**environment.php**

```
<?php
//Get the environment
$environment = getenv('ENV');
//Check if the environment has been set
if(is_string($environment) && ($environment != '')){
    //Return the environment
    return $environment;
}else{
    //On default return production environment
    return 'production';
}
```

Then in "app/bootstrap/start.php"

**start.php**

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    //Return the environment we're currently using
    return require __DIR__.'/environment.php';

});
```

Works perfect for me.